# Simply have link to URL in email sent from Excel

Tags: excel, email, url, hyperlink, vba

This seems simple enough. I am sending an email from Excel using a Macros. In the body of the email there is a web address.

Example:

For helpful hints on coding go to our website: https:stackoverflow.com or visit https:google.com

I keep getting a compile error. I would like the person receiving the email to be able to click on the address and link to the website.

Thanks

Comment: Care to share the error and the code that's causing you issues?

Comment: compile error: sub or function not defined

Comment: Again we would need to see part of your code. Because you are trying to make a call to a sub that doesn't exist. You need to add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module. You need to ensure you are declaring all of your variables. But it's 100% impossible for anyone to tell you exactly what your issue is without seeing some code.

Comment: You are more than welcome to replace any personal information (and it's strongly recommended that you do), such as website addresses like you did above. But the replacements need to match the general idea of what you are wanting to accomplish.

Comment: correction. It is giving me a syntax error

Comment: Email_Body = "Dear " & name & "," & Chr(11) _
       & "Thank you for you question " & Chr(11) _
       & "We will get back to you within 24 hours." & Chr(11)
       & "IMPORTANT: Please remember to you may find answers to your question on our website: https://forhelp.com. If you do not find a solution here." & Char(11) _
       & "Please refer to Instructions available on the our intranet: https://developer.com/faq/." & Char(11) _
       & "All listed answers are not perfect." & questions & chr(11)

Comment: @K.Davis The line continuation character can come anywhere within the statement (other than in the middle of a token) so `_ &` is as good as `& _`.

Comment: @Toya Please update the question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48308709/edit) link you will find just below it, and include the code there - it is nearly impossible to correctly read code written in comments.

Comment: FWIW, your syntax error is probably due to the `;` after the string literal `"Please refer to Instructions available on the our intranet: developer.com/faq/."`, and your sub or function not defined is due to your `Char` function calls. (Do you have a function called `Char`, or is that a typo?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Email_Body = "Dear " & Name & "," & Chr(11) & _
    "Thank you for you question " & Chr(11) & _
    "We will get back to you within 24 hours." & _
    Chr(11) & "IMPORTANT: Please remember to " & _
    "you may find answers to your question on " & _
    "our website: forhelp.com. If you do not " & _
    "find a solution here." & Chr(11) & _
    "Please refer to Instructions available on the " & _
    "our intranet: developer.com/faq/.;" & Chr(11) & _
    "All listed answers are not perfect." & questions & Chr(11)
```

If you still have issues, ensure that `Name` & `questions` are properly declared variables.

Also, Ensure that `Email_Body` is assigned to your outlook object. It should look something like:

```
With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    .Email_Body = ...
End With
```

with `OutApp` being the object referencing your outlook application/email.